# Why is sorting modifing the original in this case?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I had a problem that was making the original array to change, the curious thing is that adding `arr.join("...").split("...")` seems to prevent this:

A little background:

- my script creates and adds stuff to an `array`
- this array initialized empty like `arr=[]`
- the things are added passing `arr[index] = "..."`
- then I want to have a copy of the `arr` but sorted
- when I do the sorting, the orignial `arr` is modified

Here is a simplified version of what is going on:

```
var arr=[], sorted;

arr[0] = "hello";
arr[1] = "world";

//buggy, the original is sorted
//sorted = arr.sort(function(a,b){return (a.length-b.length);});

sorted = arr.join("improbableCollision").split("improbableCollision").sort(function(a,b){return (a.length-b.length);});
```

- Why adding `.join("*").split("*")` solves the problem?
- What was causing the problem?
- Is there a more elegant way to fix this?

For the full script, check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gpXzd/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sort without all that joining and splitting, copy the array with slice or concat:

var sorted = arr.slice(0).sort()

Answer (score 2):

This works because the join() then split() operation results in a copy of your original array.

Comment: but why simply using `arr.sort` don't do this?, I mean, I always split/slice/etc without the fear of modifying the originals

Comment: The reason "why arr.sort() doesn't make a new copy", is, not to be cheeky, because it does not have to.  Certain sort algorithms (bubble sort, for example), do not require the allocation of a new array.  In this way, arr.sort leaves the decision of whether or not to make an copy of the original array to you.  If it always made a copy, then, in the situations where preserving the original array was not desired, unnecessary memory and processor cycles would be used.