# After sorting an array while setting a variable, the original array gets sorted too

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why is sorting modifing the original in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952598/why-is-sorting-modifing-the-original-in-this-case)

I have 2 arrays. I want to set the second variable to the sorted version of the first.

```
var _myArray = ["N","T","A","W","Z","X"];
var _array02 = _myArray.sort();

document.write(_myArray+'<br>'+_array02);
```

What should happen: `N,T,A,W,N,X<br>A,N,T,W,X,Z`

What happens instead: `A,N,T,W,X,Z<br>A,N,T,W,X,Z`

Is this by design in JS, and if so, how do I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sort()` sorts the array *in place*. Sort a copy, if you want the original array unchanged:

```
var _myArray = ["N","T","A","W","Z","X"];
var _array02 = _myArray.slice().sort();

_myArray +'\n'+_array02

/*  returned value: (String)
N,T,A,W,Z,X
A,N,T,W,X,Z
*/
```